# Flex Mobile PHP remote server

Tags: php, apache-flex, air, flash-builder

I am totally new to Flex mobile developing.
In FlashBuilder for PHP, you need to specify local PHP server.
My answer is, how to change it to remote server?
Because, i have a hosting, and I need to put files there, to make it public.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You never need a local server per say.  Have you tried to look at the files that Flash Builder creates for you (if I remember correctly, in this case it creates a service-config.xml file)?  There should be one that mentions ServiceObjects and an endpoint of localhost.  You can change this to your remote location.

I personally don't like the xml approach to creating services since it doesn't give me the flexibility I want in the code.  I much prefer having it in the code using the ServiceObject class and specifying the endpoint and destination there and using a delegate pattern to call my services.  Something for you to look into :)

Comment: Yes, thank you, I have already figured it out yesterday.
Now, it works. Thank you really much